# Simple VBA Loop with Solver

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I have the following macro in VBA, and I am trying to get it to work, but I get an error: "Compile Error: Object Required"

```
Sub Macro6()


' Macro6 Macro


Dim counts As Integer

Set counts = 27

Do While counts < 28

SolverOK SetCell:=Sheets("Slag Case_forcedConvection").Cells(counts, 66), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:=Sheets("Slag Case_forcedConvection").Cells(counts, 32)

SolverSolve userfinish:=True

   counts = counts + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set counts = 27` remove the `set`

Comment: When you get errors, be sure to tell us what line is indicated with the error

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax of a VBA Do While Loop is

```
Do While *Condition*

CODE

Loop
```

You are missing the 'Loop' at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Integers/Longs do not need to be set they only need to be defined. Objects and Ranges require the set command.

As you are using an Integer you should remove `Set` from `Set counts = 27`.

If you still get the error, it is good practice to step though your code with F8 (or break/pause the code) to see exactly which line errors are occurring on.

http://www.vbtutor.net/ provides some good tutorials for starting out in case you wanted a solid introduction to VB coding. I hope this helps...